# Javascript search in page

Tags: javascript, search

I have search in page, in Javascript
For example, if i search number 50, i see all elements with 50 in title
But if I search number 5, I want see only elements with number 5 in title, not 50 or 435, or 456.

How can i get it? Maybe anyone know?

```
<input type="text" class="sfield" id="txt-printer-search"/>

// main search function for printer 
    $(function(){
        $('#btn-printer-search').on('click',function(){
            var searchVal = $('#txt-printer-search').val();
            var allProducts = $('li.product');

            allProducts.hide();
            allProducts.removeClass('first last');

            var visibleProducts = [];
            $.each(allProducts,function(i, p){
                p = $(p);
                var printers = p.find('.gridlist-buttonwrap').html();                   
                if(printers.indexOf(searchVal)!= -1){
                    visibleProducts.push(p);
                }
            });
            showVisibleProducts(visibleProducts);
        });
```

Comment: Can you show your html? If the element only contains number you can compare it as string, otherwise maybe add single space to searchVal.

Comment: User regular expressions instead...

Answer (score 0):

I just read it but it should work. Please try with this and you should find the problem with more precision:

```
if(printers.indexOf(searchVal)!= -1){
    visibleProducts.push(p);
} else {
    console.log("Not matching with ["+searchVal+"] with :"+printers);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Javascript regex and use it like this

```
anchorForStartOfString + "5" +"anchorForEndOfString
"^"+num+"$"
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

There is also an example

Comment: not the right syntax try: `var patt=new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);`